# CSS - Hover effect on linear-gradient background

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to add a hover effect on my css property `box` which is creating a pie graph using css. I would like to add an opacity change on hover to give a more interactive look and feel to it.

When creating a pseudo-class `:hover` it is currently not having any effect. I believe this is the case due to the `background: linear-gradient` that I am using in order to achieve a pie graph look.

I've attempted to work around this by using a `:before` class and adding a rgba background to this pseudo-class then adding a `:hover` effect to it which did have no effect on my display also.

Here is a code snippet of what I've attempted:

```css
.box {
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);

  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
 background: linear-gradient(var(--v), #ffffff 50%,transparent 0) 0 /calc(100% - var(--s)*100%), linear-gradient(var(--v), #002F65 50%,transparent 0) 0 /calc(var(--s)*100%), linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%,#002F65 0);
 }
 
     .box:before {
        width: 78px;
        height: 78px;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8))
    }
 
 .box:hover:before {
   opacity: 1
 }
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:45;--s:0"></div>
```

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/35p4aqzd/?

Answer (score 0):

```
.box:hover:before {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

The opacity value of 1 means default, so if you will lower its value like '0.5' then it will give you the fade out effect. Also, the value of 0 will give you a transparent effect. So you can choose your values between 0 to 1.

```
.box:hover:before {
   content: '';
   opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

To see your result when using `:before`, you should add the `content:'';` property.

```css
.box {
  --v:calc( ((18/5) * var(--p) - 90)*1deg);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: linear-gradient(var(--v), #ffffff 50%,transparent 0) 0 /calc(100% - var(--s)*100%), linear-gradient(var(--v), #002F65 50%,transparent 0) 0 /calc(var(--s)*100%), linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 50%,#002F65 0);
 }
 
.box:before {
 /*   added 1 line of code; changed width, height, and border's value    */
  content: '';
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}
 
.box:hover:before {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="--p:45;--s:0"></div>
```

you can try this if you want the entire pie to fade

```
    .box:hover{
       content: '';
       opacity: 0.5;
     }
```